# Fluent 1.2 Join statement not working

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to get fluent 1.2 to work on a project that currently uses v1.1. However the existing join code no longer works. I specify a Join in the map but it never appears in the SQL.

I have a class hierarchy mapped which includes a join (see below). The application uses some legacy tables that cannot be changed. Alternatively I could rewrite the code so that the joined properties can be mapped with a reference. However this is not really valid as it produces a domain object that does not exist.

```
 public class IndividualMap : SubclassMap<Individual>
    {
        public IndividualMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.Title);
           .....



            Join("UserDefFields", x =>
            {
                x.KeyColumn("id");
                x.Map(y => y.MembershipEnquirySource, "Anl9");
               ....
            }
          );
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm still having the problem.

Comment: I had to create another domain object and add it as a reference unfortunately. The benefits of upgrading were greater than this slight 'dirtying' on the domain